# Merge branch A into branch B and keep B's commits on top in Git

Tags: git, git-merge

I am looking for a way to merge my `master` branch into my `test` branch, while keeping my commits in `test` on top (after `master` is merged in).

What's the appropriate way of doing it?

Comment: Sounds like you want `rebase`.

Comment: Be very, VERY careful with ``rebase`` if you're working on a branch that is pushed remotely though.

Comment: Please read [Pro Git: 3.6 Git Branching - Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Git is to use `rebase`. Let's say that you want to update branch B with changes from branch A, but you want to keep your work on B "on top" of the new work in A. Then

```bash
git checkout B
git rebase A

# Or in one command
git rebase A B
```

The result is that all the commits that are in B, but not in A, will be re-committed on top of the new commits in A.

### Important

**Do not force push your rebased commits to a remote repo unless you're the only person working on a branch, or you're sure that other users who are sharing the branch with you are OK with you force pushing changes.**

Because B's commits are ***rewritten***, they will have new sha IDs, so Git won't consider the new commits to be the same as the old commits with their old IDs, even though they contain the same content.

This is important if you're sharing branch B with other people, because they might have the old versions of B's commits (including all of the old sha IDs). Your new commits will conflict with their old ones, unless they take extra steps to update their own commits with your new ones.

While it's possible for your collaborators to update their old commits with your new rebased ones, most people would consider this to be too troublesome to be worth it, and so rewriting shared branches/commit-history is generally frowned upon and discouraged.

When you try to push your newly rewritten branch B to a remote repo, the remote will reject the push because the new rewritten commits won't be a fast-forward update. The only way to have the push succeed is to overwrite the old commits by force-pushing. It's OK to force push if no one else is sharing your branch, but it's generally discouraged when the branch ***is shared***, for the reasons I stated above about collaborators having to put in extra effort to synchronize their old commits with your new ones.

### See Also

- [Pro Git: 3.6 Git Branching - Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).
- The [Official Linux Kernel git-rebase(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html).